# Where is the sendgrid-php.php file in SendGrid's PHP library?

Tags: php, email, sendgrid, include-path

Where is the sendgrid-php.php file that I need to include in my script to send mail through SendGrid using SendGrid's PHP library from Github?

I've downloaded SendGrid's PHP library from https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php, and I'm looking to include sendgrid-php.php in my script. I am NOT using Composer.

My include looks like:

```
require("../lib/sendgrid-2016/sendgrid-php.php");

$from = new SendGrid\Email(null, "from@test.com");
$subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid PHP Library";
$to = new SendGrid\Email(null, "to@test.com");
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", "some text here");
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

$apiKey = getenv('MY API KEY');
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
echo $response->statusCode();
echo $response->headers();
echo $response->body();
```

When I run my script I get the error:

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '../lib/sendgrid-2016/sendgrid-php.php'

Looking at the files included in the zip on Github, I don't even see the file:
[file list from github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9qPH.png)

Comment: It's wherever you put the directory that you downloaded.  It's definitely there.  At the same level as LICENSE.txt and README.md

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might have downloaded the repo .zip (generated by github) rather than the packaged zip mentioned in the readme: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php#alternative-install-package-from-zip